# Caption inside table and listoftables

Tags: tables

I currently use a straightforward solution to get captions inside the table.
However it does not allow the tables to be listed in the "\listoftables":
Example:
[image]
and the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\refstepcounter{table} \label{mytable}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
Table \ref{mytable}: The test table\\\hline
contents\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to get \listoftables working with my solution?
Thank you for any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's relatively easy.  Look at the aux file to see how a normal caption does it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\refstepcounter{table} \label{mytable}
\addcontentsline{lot}{table}{\string\numberline{\thetable}{The test table}}%
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
Table \thetable: The test table\\\hline
contents\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, great solution!
For future reference, which aux file did you check to find this?

Comment: Every time you run LaTeX you generate an aux file (same name as the PDF or log file but with a different extension).  You can find the default \caption code in source2e.pdf from ctan.